# Error using regex. Assertion error : Got <class 'str'>, expected <class 'list'>`

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am trying to implement a function using regex to remove tags and return back a list of the strings found in the text file. However, the following error occurs:

`AssertionError: Wrong type for output extracted_words. Got <class 'str'>, expected <class 'list'>`

This is my code below, help would be appreciated with this.

```
import re

def get_words(text):
    """
    Extracting words from the text

    The 'text' parameter is the file which contains strings inside

    Objective: To return a list of strings found in the text called 'extracted_words'
    """
    # Implementation
    extracted_words = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', text)
    return extracted_words
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Please provide a [MCVE].  The relevant `assert` statement would also be useful.

Comment: `re.sub` won’t return a list since it works similarly to `str.replace`. Did you mean to use `re.match`?

Comment: When I tried that I got. '`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'` @NChauhan

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
rgxp = re.compile(r'([^<>]+)(?=<)')
return re.findall(rgxp, text)
```